How to insert a non-breaking space in PL/SQL
I've found various threads about trimming non-breaking spaces in Oracle PL/SQL but I haven't found a single one telling me how to add one at the beginning of a string.
I've tried &nbsp and chr(160) but none of them work. I need a space at the beginning of a line that will not be trimmed by standard tools I cannot influence/configure differently.
Thanks in advance
infy

Use CHR(160).
SELECT DUMP(CHR(160)),
       DUMP(TRIM(CHR(160)))
FROM   DUAL;

Outputs:



DUMP(CHR(160))
DUMP(TRIM(CHR(160)))




Typ=1 Len=1: 160
Typ=1 Len=1: 160



In the left column, CHR(160) gives a string with length 1 containing a single character with the ASCII code 160 (a non-breaking space) and applying TRIM to it, in the right column, you get the same output.

Alternatively, use ' ' (a string containing the Non-Breaking space character):
SELECT DUMP(' '),
       DUMP(TRIM(' ')),
       LENGTH(' ')
FROM   DUAL;

Which outputs:



DUMP(' ')
DUMP(TRIM(' '))
LENGTH(' ')




Typ=96 Len=2: 194,160
Typ=1 Len=2: 194,160
1



or UNISTR('\00A0') (160 decimal = A0 hexadecimal):
SELECT DUMP(UNISTR('\00A0')),
       DUMP(TRIM(UNISTR('\00A0'))),
       LENGTH(UNISTR('\00A0'))
FROM   DUAL;




DUMP(UNISTR('\00A0'))
DUMP(TRIM(UNISTR('\00A0')))
LENGTH(UNISTR('\00A0'))




Typ=1 Len=2: 0,160
Typ=1 Len=2: 0,160
1



In both those cases, a multi-byte character is generated. For the literal it is a VARCHAR2 and for UNISTR it is a NVARCHAR2 (which is why the first byte of the multi-byte character differs, as they are using different encodings).
fiddle

It was too simple. If anyone ever struggles like me, you won't have to ask a stupid question like this, simply type ALT+0160 and you have your special character in PL/SQL code

Why would you want a special character in PL/SQL code ?? The only place such a character would make sense is within a string that is the contents of a column in SQL or a variable, not in code itself. Look at MT0's answer - the proper way to embed special chars in strings within Oracle (whether used within PL/SQL or not) is with CHR.

Well it was a logging string that I needed this for in order to not have it trimmed by logging processors automatically. It wasn't actually needed for real code, sorry for the incorrect wording. But still, adding the character to an existing string didn't work with plain "|| chr(160" which was my first attempt.

var_string := 'whatever'||CHR(160)||'whatever';
